# Rate Limits , error : 'blocked'

Tags: nest-api

I have a product registered and planning to use 10 Nest cameras (which is the max limit).

I am currently receiving error: 'blocked' in the response which I read from the documentation is due to rate limits.

How do I come out of blocked state ?

Also rate limits are applicable for every device that is every camera , or for a product or for the access token of the product ?

Answer (score 1):

For the NestCam, there are different limits depending on whether you have a Nest Aware subscription for the camera or not.

The rate limit for Cameras depending on what you are trying to to. For Snapshots pictures (snapshot_url) without Nest-Aware is 2/minute and for cameras with nest aware it is 10/minute.

For other API uses, there are Per Device/Structure limits and per Access token limits.

You can review the rate-limit documentation on the Nest API website at
   https://developers.nest.com/documentation/cloud/data-rate-limits/